# WCF and Authentication

Tags: wcf, authentication

how to design WCF service that when user will going to access it then he has to pass user id & password. help me with small code. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WCF Security Guidance](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex has lots of those "how do I do this...." kind of samples for anything security related.

For your case, you might want to look at:

[How To – Use Username Authentication with the SQL Server Membership Provider and Message Security in WCF from Windows Forms](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Use%20Username%20Authentication%20with%20the%20SQL%20Membership%20Provider%20and%20Message%20Security%20in%20WCF%20from%20Windows%20Forms&referringTitle=Home)

or check out all the other "How-To's" to find the one matching your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [an article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131.aspx) you could read.